# Build same job with two JDK

Tags: java, jenkins

I try to build a job on jenkins (multibranch pipeline). And i need to run this job with a JDK8 and JDK 6 for a test.

How can i install different JDK and how can i define which JDK he has to use ?

thank you

Comment: Did you check the manual already? What have you tried so far? Pleasse show us some code, we are code monkeys here.

Comment: I tried the JDK parameter plugin but it works only on freestyle projects. I installed (in the Jenkins overall configuration of tools) JDK8 and JDK6, but the project does not arise to the question. Otherwise I did not touch my Jenkinsfile or other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Set `JAVA_HOME`

Given that you got both JDK's installed in your Jenkins, you can create two different stages and set the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable for each of them. Something like this:

```
pipeline {

    stage("jdk6") {
        environment {
            JAVA_HOME = "/usr/lib/jvm/oracle-java6-jdk-amd64"
        }
        steps {
            sh "java -version"
            sh "mvn --version"
        }
    }
    stage("jdk8") {
        environment {
            JAVA_HOME = "/usr/lib/jvm/oracle-java8-jdk-amd64"
        }
        steps {
            sh "java -version"
            sh "mvn --version"
        }
    }
}
```

### Use Jenkins' Global Tools

Alternatively you can configure your needed JDK's under "Manage Jenkins" → "Global Tool Configuration". Note that and utilize it with the [`tools` directive](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#tools):

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {

        stage("jdk6") {
            tools {
                jdk "jdk6"
                maven "3.2.5" // latest Maven, which supports JDK 6
            }
            steps {
                sh "java -version"
                sh "mvn --version"
            }
        }

        stage("jdk8") {
            tools {
                jdk "jdk8"
                maven "3.5.4"
            }
            steps {
                sh "java -version"
                sh "mvn --version"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I also needed to change the Maven version, since JDK 6 is no longer supported by current Maven versions (see [Maven Release History](https://maven.apache.org/docs/history.html)).

Comment: i did this but like that :
stage("test Java 6") {
        environment {
            JAVA_HOME = "/home/jdk/jdk1.6.0_181"
        }
        steps {
            // build here, e.g. mvn test
        }
    }
But now, jenkins tell me :
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
  We cannot execute /home/jdk/jdk1.6.0_45/bin/java

Comment: @KarlJanssoone And there is a Java 6 installed under the path?

Comment: OK. Well setting `JAVA_HOME` obviously worked. Can user `jenkins` execute `/home/jdk/jdk1.6.0_181/bin/java -version`?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i found a soluce to resolve this problem

In the file pom.xml i define a plugin like this :

[pom.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsvTi.png)

Like that, i can define in my Jenkinsfile which version of jdk i use.

And in my Jenkinsfile i define stage like this :

[Jenkinsfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcEVJ.png)

with this, i haven't problem with compatibility